# Optimizing code structure C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

Here's code I write to check if properties in my viewmodel are null or not before attempting to update the database

```
   var channel = _context.Channels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Part))
            {
                channel.Part = viewModel.Part;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.IndexName))
            {
                channel.IndexName = viewModel.IndexName;
            }
            if (viewModel.MeasurementId != null)
            {
                channel.MeasurementId = viewModel.MeasurementId;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Direction))
            {
                channel.Direction = viewModel.Direction;
            }
```

The code is working fine but I use alot of if statements here which for me doesn't look really effective. Can you suggest me changes like using other syntax or structures rather than if statement to make my code more concise and abit more "pro"?

Comment: You can use a tool like Automapper to map your viewmodel to your entity

Comment: @Vsevolod Is that something la value injector?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, it transfers the values from one object to another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your channel object's properties do not have any side-effects other than changing a value (ie, firing events), you could do this:

```
string PickNonEmptyOrDefault(string value, string deflt)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? deflt : value;
}

...

channel.Part = PickNonEmptyOrDefault(viewModel.Part, channel.Part);
channel.IndexName = PickNonEmptyOrDefault(viewModel.IndexName, channel.IndexName);
etc.
```

By the way, I wanted to know if there was a way this could be done without accidentally side effecting your property. The trick is to use reflection and to use a `PropertyInfo` object to do your work:

```
    class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
        public string Baz { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return (Bar ?? "") + " " + (Baz ?? "");
        }
    }
    delegate void propsetter(string prop, string value);

    private static void SetOnNonEmpty(PropertyInfo pi, Object o, string value)
    {
        if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            throw new ArgumentException("type mismatch on property");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            pi.SetValue(o, value);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var myObj = new Foo();
        myObj.Baz = "nothing";
        PropertyInfo piBar = myObj.GetType().GetProperty("Bar");
        PropertyInfo piBaz = myObj.GetType().GetProperty("Baz");

        SetOnNonEmpty(piBar, myObj, "something");
        SetOnNonEmpty(piBaz, myObj, null);
        Console.WriteLine(myObj);
    }
```

output `something nothing`

I honestly don't recommend doing this as it doesn't really add to the readability and feels pretty gross.

I'd be more inclined to write a chunk of code that reflects across the properties of your view model and calls a `Func<string, string>` to get the corresponding property name in your data model and then if that returns non-null and the property types match, call the getter on the view object and pass it to the setter on the data object.

And I would only do this if I was doing this a significant number of times.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just the `if` that bothers you you could use the conditional operator:

```
channel.Part = string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Part) ? 
               channel.Part : viewModel.Part;
etc.
```

of course that *always* calls the `set` accessor for `Part`, which is fine unless there's logic in it (change tracking, etc.) that would be bad if it were called when the value doesn't really change.

You could also refactor the conditional operator to a method, but there's no other way to *conditionally* set the value without using an `if`.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code you have written.

If your objective is less lines of code, you can do this, however I think it will just add unnecessary complexity.

```
channel.Part = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.Part) ? channel.Part : viewModel.Part;
channel.IndexName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.IndexName) ? channel.IndexName: viewModel.IndexName;
channel.MeasurementId = viewModel.MeasurementId == null ? channel.MeasurementId : viewModel.MeasurementId;
channel.Direction = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.Direction) ? channel.Direction : viewModel.Direction;
```

Note I have switched your call from IsNullOrEmpty to IsNullOrWhiteSpace

A string with the value of " " (one or more whitespace) will get through a IsNullOrEmpty check which you probably dont want.

You can also use the coalesce operator for your nullable types (but not empty strings) like this...

```
channel.MeasurementId = viewModel.MeasurementId ?? channel.MeasurementId;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. Even [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) uses `if` statements.

If you want the best performing code, keep it like this. If you want to make your code look *pro*, use any suggestion done by others here. My opinion: keep it as is.

Answer (score 0):

If those are fields and not properties, you can use something like this:

```
void ReplaceIfNotEmpty(ref string destination, string source)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    {
        destination = source;
    }
}
```

and then just

```
ReplaceIfNotEmpty(ref channel.Part, viewModel.Part);
```

Comment: You need a `ref` before `channel.Part` and `channel.Part` cannot be a property.

Comment: You can't pass a property as a 'ref' parameter.